# How to access property file in user.home directory?

Tags: java, properties, environment-variables

How can I access a property file called `test.property` in `user.home`?

This doesn't work:

```
public class Properties {

    private static java.util.Properties p = new java.util.Properties();

    static {
        try {
            String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
            home += "\\test.properties";
            System.out.println("User home: " + home);
            InputStream is = Properties.class.getResourceAsStream(home);
            p.load(is);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("property file could not be found!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As an aside, it is better to put application properties into a sub-directory of `user.home` based on the package name of the main class.  This helps avoid *your* (poorly named) `test.properties` from overwriting *my* (poorly named) `test.properties` (or vice-versa).

Comment: @dooonot For future reference, "doesn't work", is not an appropriate way of describing a problem. Posting the code is the first step, the next is posting what actually happens, i.e., what output are you getting, exceptions, etc. Don't just assume that people will not only compile and run your code, but also get the same results you are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File propsFile = new File(home, "test.properties");
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(propsFile);
```

You will probably find that the `user.home` is not on the run-time class-path of the application.  In that case, use a `File` instead.